rsample group_bootstrap is ~2000 times slower than bootstrap. Why?
The package rsample contains a function for bootstrapping and another function which allows bootstrapping on groups of the data.
The grouped vesion is a lot slower (~2000 times). I was expecting it to be a bit slower, but I do not get why it is that much slower.
(The groups in my example are not meaningful, but this should be irrelevant for testing the speed of both functions.)
library(tidyverse)
library(rsample)

dat <- tibble(x = 1:1000)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  grouped = {
    dat %>%
      group_bootstraps(group = x, times = 10)}, 
  simple = {
    dat %>%
      bootstraps(times = 10)},
  times = 5)



An alternative to grouping is bootstrapping on data which is nested on the grouping variable.
dat <- tibble(x = rep(1:1000, 2), y = 1:2000) 

f <- function(df, column){
  tibble(
    "estimate" = mean(pull(df, {{column}})),
    "term" = "mean"
  )
}


# Version 1 using rsample::group_bootstraps
start_time <- Sys.time()

dat %>%
  group_bootstraps(group = x, times = 10) %>%
  mutate(mean_stats = purrr::map(splits, ~ f(analysis(.), y))) %>% 
  int_pctl(mean_stats)

print(difftime(Sys.time(), start_time, units = "secs"))

# Version 2 using tidyr nest and unnest
start_time <- Sys.time()
dat %>%
  nest(.by = x) %>%
  bootstraps(times = 10) %>%
  mutate(mean_stats = purrr::map(splits, ~ f(unnest(analysis(.), data), y))) %>% 
  int_pctl(mean_stats)

print(difftime(Sys.time(), start_time, units = "secs"))

This is roughly 10 times slower than not grouping at all which is much better than the grouping function in the package for my specific problem.
I think the downside is that it is not guaranteed to have the same number of rows across all resamples, especially if the groups have different number of rows.

I'm able to replicate your timings!
Rather than dive into the technical reasons for that slowdown, a couple thoughts:

In a typical modeling pipeline, the time to generate these resamples in either case is negligible compared to the time that modeling functions likely take when training. We focus on optimizing those longer-running pieces.
Your example of bootstrapping 1000 groups, each with one observation, is a worst-case for the function's performance relative to its ungrouped friend; there are no variables other than the grouping variable and every row is its own group.
An example more similar to the contexts we expect the function to actually be used in results in more similar timings (~50x in the case from the function documentation):

library(tidyverse)
library(rsample)

data(ames, package = "modeldata")

set.seed(1)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  grouped = {
    ames %>%
      group_bootstraps(group = Neighborhood, times = 10)}, 
  simple = {
    ames %>%
      bootstraps(times = 10)},
  times = 5)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>     expr        min         lq     mean     median         uq       max neval
#>  grouped 214.892521 217.795854 228.4819 219.397355 228.345646 261.97791     5
#>   simple   4.314799   4.617092   4.6412   4.665144   4.775475   4.83349     5
#>  cld
#>   a 
#>    b

Created on 2024-05-16 with reprex v2.1.0
EDIT: FYI, this issue is indeed tracked on rsample! Here's a link. Feel free to upvote to encourage us to bring that to the top of our to-do list.
Simon, tidymodels team

Thanks I posted a comment on the issue. Where can I vote?

Using a thumbs-up emoji react on the original issue description in the linked issue!
